# hiring a web designer: design task

Tags: design

I need to hire a web designer. How do I test his creativity and skills before I hire him. Ideally I'd like to give him a fairly open-ended task i.e. I give him a problem statement and ask him to design a PSD file.

Any suggestions on the problem statement I might give him? Also, is there a better way to hire /test a web designer?

Comment: I don't think this is a good approach. Making a solid PSD mockup is a task that usually takes days, not hours. If you doing this, you better be paying for there time.

Answer (score 6):

You can always ask for:

- Previous work
- Examples of design
- Mockups / thoughts / ideas before you commit to a design

Answer (score 3):

I just asked a designer sat across from me - he said he wouldn't perform the task but rely on his portfolio.

Are you testing the potential designer's competency with his/her tools or want a feel for their style/output/approach? Examples of previous work is a better way, talk to a past client or two, and listen for what feedback/ideas they have when talking to you. They might mock up one or two (roughly, not finished articles).

Comment: I'm looking for the right approach. Also, since I will hire an experienced designer, I don't want to waste time training him on basic web design best practices.